# What Does The relative(to:) Function Actually Do?

Tags: swift, collections, range, swift4

This is from the [Swift Standard Library Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangeexpression/2894878-relative):

> `relative(to:)`
>
> Returns the range of indices within the given collection described by this range expression.

Here is the method signature:

```
func relative<C>(to collection: C) -> Range<Self.Bound> where C : _Indexable, Self.Bound == C.Index
```

Along with its explanation:

> **Parameters**
>
> *collection*
>
> The collection to evaluate this range expression in relation to.
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A range suitable for slicing collection. The returned range is not guaranteed to be inside the bounds of collection. Callers should apply the same preconditions to the return value as they would to a range provided directly by the user.

Finally, here is my test code:

```
let continuousCollection = Array(0..<10)
var range = 0..<5
print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection))
//0..<5
range = 5..<15
print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection))
//5..<15
range = 11..<15
print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection))
//11..<15
let disparateCollection = [1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 12, 13, 16, 18, 19, 22]
range = 0..<5
print(range.relative(to: disparateCollection))
//0..<5
range = 5..<15
print(range.relative(to: disparateCollection))
//5..<15
range = 11..<15
print(range.relative(to: disparateCollection))
//11..<15
```

In every case, `relative(to:)` just returns the original range. What is this method supposed to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`relative(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangeexpression/2894878-relative) is a requirement of the [`RangeExpression`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangeexpression) protocol, which Swift's range types conform to in Swift 4.

This includes:

- Half-open ranges created with the infix `..<` operator ([`Range`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/range) & [`CountableRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countablerange))
- Closed ranges created with the infix `...` operator ([`ClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/closedrange) & [`CountableClosedRange`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countableclosedrange))
- The partial ranges introduced in [SE-0172](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md), including:

  - Left-handed ranges created with the *postfix* `...` operator ([`PartialRangeFrom`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/PartialRangeFrom) & [`CountablePartialRangeFrom`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countablePartialRangeFrom))
  - Closed right-handed ranges created with the prefix `...` operator ([`PartialRangeUpTo`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/PartialRangeUpTo))
  - Half-open right-handed ranges created with the prefix `..<` operator  ([`PartialRangeThrough`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/PartialRangeThrough))

As the documentation states, calling `relative(to:)` on a range expression with a given `Collection` (where the range has bounds that match the `Index` type of the collection) returns a `Range` suitable for slicing that collection.

In the case of half-open ranges, the bounds just stay the same, as you've observed. However, the results will differ with other range types. For example, with closed ranges, the upper bound will need to be incremented (as it's no longer inclusive). With partial ranges, the missing lower or upper bounds need to be "filled in" by the collection's `startIndex` or `endIndex` respectively.

For example:

```
let continuousCollection = Array(0 ..< 10)

do {
    let range = 0 ..< 5 // CountableRange
    print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection)) // 0..<5
}

do {
    let range = 0 ... 5 // ClosedCountableRange
    print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection)) // 0..<6
}

do {
    let range = 4... // CountablePartialRangeFrom
    print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection)) // 4..<10
}

do {
    let range = ..<9 // PartialRangeUpTo
    print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection)) // 0..<9
}

do {
    let range = ...3 // PartialRangeThrough
    print(range.relative(to: continuousCollection)) // 0..<4
}
```

The `relative(to:)` requirement of `RangeExpression` then allows the standard library, amongst other things, to write [a generic ranged subscript on `Collection`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/73ba66a/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift.gyb#L1146), allowing an arbitrary collection to be subscripted with an arbitrary range type with `Index` bound(s):

```
let continuousCollection = Array(0 ..< 10)

print(continuousCollection[0 ..< 5]) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(continuousCollection[0 ... 5]) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(continuousCollection[4...]) // [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(continuousCollection[..<9]) // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
print(continuousCollection[...3]) // [0, 1, 2, 3]
```